# Out proc session for different applications in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, iis

I was trying to create an asp.net application with session state as out proc. (State server). When following the steps given [in this article](http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/07/01/web-farms-in-net-and-iis-part-5-session-state-management/) it was mentioned as we require to set the sessionstate in our IIS and we need to start an asp.net state service in our service management. My question is, if i change in IIS will it not affect the session handling of other applications? what if i have 2 applications and i want only one application to have session mode as out proc and other as inproc.. in this case changing in iis will require other applications hosted in that iis to follow out proc mode of session handling?
Please let me understand this in detail. Please let me know if further information required on this if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of IIS are you using? If it is on Windows Server 2008 R2 or greater Session state is configurable on a per application basis(the configuration is actually stored in the application's web.config file).

Rather than going to Session state at the root website node as they have done in your link expand out so you can see the application you want to change, select it and then select Session state and select the session storage you want the application to use.

The default Session setting is InProc for .Net applications so I suggest changing the one you want to use the State Server.